# Traversing a recursive relations matrix in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, matrix, checkbox

There are lot of elements (expressed as checkboxes) with some different relations. For example:

- A needs B
- A needs C
- A can't be combined with D
- B can't be combined with E
- D needs E
- C needs F
- F can't be combined with G
- S can't be combined with B
- T can't be combined with D
- U needs S

**Edit:** 3 questions came up in the answers, that I want to define here:

- Q: What is the default, prohibited or needed? A: None of them. If
  there is no relation between 2 elements, they can act independently
  (as long there are no relations to a common element which would say
  otherwise).
- Q: If A prohibits B, does B then automatically prohibit A? A: Yes.
  The cat (A) says, you can't have it with a dog (B). Even if the dog
  doesn't care about the cat, you can't combine them, because the cat
  won't like it.
- Q: If A needs B, does B then automatically need A? A: No. If you want
  to read stackoverflow (A), you need the browser (B). But if you want
  to use the browser (B), you don't need stackoverflow (A).

**Edit:** I want to give a more simple example. Let's say, you can configure a car with checkboxes. There are some rules. For example, if you choose black paint, you can't choose white interior color (prohibited). If you choose leather seats, you can do this only in combination with seat heating (needed) and leather steering wheel (needed), but can't combine it with electric seat regulation (prohibited). Seat heating is not possible with white interior (prohibited), while a white roof needs white interior. Hence, even if not defined, you can't have white roof with seat heating (prohibited due to relations with a common element).

So if someone activates checkbox A, the checkboxes B and C need to be activated, too, while checkbox D needs to be disabled. Since A needs B and B can't be combined with E, checkbox E needs to be disabled, too. Since C needs F, F needs to be activated. And since F can't be combined with G, G needs to be deactivated as well.

And the other way round: If someone activates E, then B needs to be deactivated, since B can't be combined with E. But D doesn't need to be activated, because D needs E while E doesn't need D necessarily.

The big questions are now:

1. How to ideally express the relations in javascript
2. How to check all the relations with javascript if someone activates
   a checkbox.

The problem is the recursion. Every action leads to more actions which lead (possibly) to even more actions.

Following logic should apply for the example, that "A" is activated:

1. B will be activated
2. C will be activated
3. D will be disabled
4. E will be disabled
5. S will be disabled
6. T will be disabled
7. U will be disabled

Current definitions of the relations (can be changed):

```
var relations = {
  'A': {
    'B': 'needed',
    'C': 'needed',
    'D': 'prohibited'
  },
  'B': {
    'E': 'prohibited'
  },
  'D': {
    'E': 'needed'
  },
  'C': {
    'F': 'needed'
  },
  'F': {
    'G': 'prohibited'
  },
  'S': {
    'B': 'prohibited'
  },
  'T': {
    'D': 'prohibited'
  },
  'U': {
    'S': 'needed'
  }
}
```

Current theoretical approach:

Assumed a click on "A":

```
foreach (relations['A'] as related, relation) {
  if (relation === 'needed') {
    // take action
    activateRelated(related);
  } else if (relation === 'prohibited') {
    // take action
    disableRelated(related);
  }
}
```

But that's only the first iteration. Theoretically this could be a function which calls itself recursively after each action is taken. But on, let's say 300 Elements with a lot of relations, it loops infinite. 
Well, it works fine if one action is taken, one checkbox is activated. In a more realistic scenario, there are 30 to 50 % of the checkboxes active and the checking of the relations needs to go the whole way up and down.

Second problem is: if the user disables the checkbox A again, all relations need to be checked again - for all still active checkboxes, too.

Comment: wouldn't it be better if you change the logic to `... 'A': { needed: ['B', 'C'], prohibited: ['D'] } ...`? the iteration over the object keys is more work than to change the data structure to a more easy access.

Comment: That would be possible as well, of course. The data is more complex in reality. It's more like `... 'A': { 'B': { 'needed': true, 'modifier': -3.4, 'info': 'text' } ...`. But of course, the extra data could be extracted into an additional object. I am not bound to the logic definition posted in the question.

Comment: suppose you have selected B, D, E, what dou you expect to get?

Comment: Suppose my code works, it's not possible to select B, D and E. If B is selected, E is disabled. And since E is needed be D, D is disabled as well.

Comment: hm, that's wired, because B -> not E, D -> E, a flip flop. it would be better if the list is more completed, to prevent instable state.

Comment: Sorry, my prior comments was uncompleted. Suppose my code works, it's not possible to select B, D and E. If B is selected (as first): disables E, D, S. If D is selected (as first action): disables A, T, B and checks/activates E. If E is selected (first): disables B, A.

Comment: What about S and A? S disables B and A enables B, and so on.

Comment: That's right, if S is still available. Isn't always with the prior selection of B, D or E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps. If works with hints below the form.

Edit: Now with simple check for circular reference. Selected items which affect each other became deselected first.

Edit 2: Now with disabling/enabling of checkboxes.

```js
var relation = [
        { name: 'A', needed: ['B', 'C'], prohibited: ['D'] },
        { name: 'B', needed: [], prohibited: ['E'] },
        { name: 'C', needed: ['F'], prohibited: [] },
        { name: 'D', needed: ['E'], prohibited: [] },
        { name: 'E', needed: [], prohibited: [] },
        { name: 'F', needed: [], prohibited: ['G'] },
        { name: 'G', needed: [], prohibited: [] },
        { name: 'S', needed: [], prohibited: ['B'] },
        { name: 'T', needed: [], prohibited: ['D'] },
        { name: 'U', needed: ['S'], prohibited: [] }
    ];

void function () {
    var div = document.createElement('div'),
        form = document.createElement('form'),
        loop;
    div.id = 'out';
    form.name = 'boxes';
    relation.forEach(function (a) {            
        var br = document.createElement('br'),
            input = document.createElement('input'),
            label = document.createElement('label');                
        input.type = 'checkbox';
        input.name = a.name;
        input.addEventListener('change', check);
        label.textContent = a.name;
        label.for = a.name;
        label.appendChild(input);
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode((a.needed.length ? ' needed: ' + a.needed.join(', ') : '') + (a.prohibited.length ? ' prohibited: ' + a.prohibited.join(', ') : '')));
        form.appendChild(label);
        form.appendChild(br);
    });
    form.appendChild(div);
    document.body.appendChild(form);

    do {
        loop = false;
        relation.forEach(function (a) {
            a.needed.forEach(function (aa) {
                relation.forEach(function (b) {
                    b.prohibited.forEach(function (bb) {
                        if (aa === bb) {
                            if (!~a.prohibited.indexOf(b.name)) {
                                a.prohibited.push(b.name);
                                loop = true;
                            }
                            if (!~b.prohibited.indexOf(a.name)) {
                                b.prohibited.push(a.name);
                                loop = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    } while (loop);
}();

function check() {
    function getBox(l) { return document.boxes[l].checked; }
    function setBox(l, v) { return document.boxes[l].checked = v; }
    function setBoxDisabled(l, v) { return document.boxes[l].disabled = v; }

    var disabled, msg, loop;

    do {
        disabled = [];
        msg = [];
        loop = false;
        relation.forEach(function (a) {
            if (getBox(a.name)) {
                a.needed.forEach(function (b) {
                    if (!getBox(b)) {
                        msg.push('With ' + a.name + ', ' + b + ' is required');
                        setBox(b, true);
                        loop = true;
                    }
                });
                a.prohibited.forEach(function (b) {
                    if (getBox(b)) {
                        msg.push('With ' + a.name + ', ' + b + ' is prohibited');
                        setBox(b, false);
                        loop = true;
                    }
                    setBoxDisabled(b, true);
                    !~disabled.indexOf(b) && disabled.push(b);
                });
            }
        });
        relation.forEach(function (a) {
            if (!getBox(a.name)) {
                a.prohibited.forEach(function (b) {
                    !~disabled.indexOf(b) && setBoxDisabled(b, false);
                });
            }
        });
        msg.length && out(msg.join('<br>') + '<hr>');
    } while (loop);
}

function out(s) {
    var node = document.createElement('div');
    node.innerHTML = s + '<br>';
    document.getElementById('out').appendChild(node);
}
```

Bonus: A slightly difference approach, featuring recursive style with proper change messages.

```js
var relation = [
        { name: 'A', needed: ['B', 'C'], prohibited: ['D'] },
        { name: 'B', needed: [], prohibited: ['E'] },
        { name: 'C', needed: ['F'], prohibited: [] },
        { name: 'D', needed: ['E'], prohibited: [] },
        { name: 'E', needed: [], prohibited: [] },
        { name: 'F', needed: [], prohibited: ['G'] },
        { name: 'G', needed: [], prohibited: [] },
        { name: 'S', needed: [], prohibited: ['B'] },
        { name: 'T', needed: [], prohibited: ['D'] },
        { name: 'U', needed: ['S'], prohibited: [] }
    ], object = {};

void function () {
    var div = document.createElement('div'),
        form = document.createElement('form');
    div.id = 'out';
    form.name = 'boxes';

    relation.forEach(function (a) {
        var br = document.createElement('br'),
            input = document.createElement('input'),
            label = document.createElement('label');

        input.type = 'checkbox';
        input.name = a.name;
        input.addEventListener('change', function (l) { return function () { checkBox(l); } }(a.name));
        //input.addEventListener('change', function () { checkBox(a.name); });
        label.textContent = a.name;
        label.for = a.name;
        label.appendChild(input);
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode((a.needed.length ? ' needed: ' + a.needed.join(', ') : '') + (a.prohibited.length ? ' prohibited: ' + a.prohibited.join(', ') : '')));
        form.appendChild(label);
        form.appendChild(br);
        object[a.name] = a;
    });
    form.appendChild(div);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
}();

function checkBox(l) {
    function getBox(l) { return document.boxes[l].checked; }
    function setBox(l, v, x) {
        if (document.boxes[l].checked !== v) {
            v ? out('With ' + x + ' option ' + l + ' is necessary.') : out('Without ' + x + ' option ' + l + ' is not valid.');
            document.boxes[l].checked = v;
        }
    }
    function setBoxDisabled(l, v, x) {
        if (document.boxes[l].disabled !== v) {
            v ? out('With ' + x + ' option ' + l + ' is not available.') : out('Without ' + x + ' option ' + l + ' is now available.');
            document.boxes[l].disabled = v;
        }
    }

    if (getBox(l)) {
        object[l].prohibited.forEach(function (p) {
            setBox(p, false, l);
            setBoxDisabled(p, true, l);
            relation.forEach(function (a) {
                if (~a.needed.indexOf(p)) {
                    setBox(a.name, false, p);
                    setBoxDisabled(a.name, true, p);
                    checkBox(a.name);
                }
            });
            checkBox(p);
        });
        object[l].needed.forEach(function (p) {
            setBox(p, true, l);
            checkBox(p);
        });
    } else {
        var allProhibited = [];
        relation.forEach(function (a) {
            if (getBox(a.name)) {
                a.prohibited.forEach(function (b) {
                    !~allProhibited.indexOf(b) && allProhibited.push(b);
                });
            }
        });
        object[l].prohibited.forEach(function (p) {
            if (!~allProhibited.indexOf(p)) {
                setBox(p, false, l);
                setBoxDisabled(p, false, l);
            }
            relation.forEach(function (a) {
                if (~a.needed.indexOf(p)) {
                    setBox(a.name, false, p);
                    setBoxDisabled(a.name, false, p);
                    checkBox(a.name);
                }
            });
            checkBox(p);
        });
        relation.forEach(function (a) {
            if (~a.needed.indexOf(l)) {
                setBox(a.name, false, l);
                checkBox(a.name);
            }
        });
    }
}

function out(s) {
    var node = document.createElement('div');
    node.innerHTML = s + '<br>';
    document.getElementById('out').appendChild(node);
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, but I can't figure out how to modify it to fit the needs. If you select A, then B/C/F will be selected as needed. Now if you select S, A will be deselected. If you select S again, B will be deselected. Actually, if A (and hence B) are selected, S can't be selected (should be disabled or just not selectable due to restrictions in relations). What already is selected, has a higher priority than what is trying to be selected. I've added some examples into my former question, marked as 2 edits.

Comment: now with diabled/enabled boxes. maybe this is working for you.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and time, I appreciate it. This seems to work great. I'll implement it into a real world example and try it with more realistic data. Can you please explain me this part: `!~a.prohibited.indexOf(b.name) && a.prohibited.push(b.name); !~b.prohibited.indexOf(a.name) && b.prohibited.push(a.name);` I don't get it.

Comment: that should prevent from having more than one entry of the same letter in the array. the tilde is a biswise not.

Comment: oh, maybe you want to know why: the problem with the former version was, i had a variable with `notTogether`, which holds opposite parts of your conditions. this is now included in the original scheme of your `prohibited` property. see here http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33674430/revisions (#5)

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:** requirements were refined

A simple recursion won't do

```
var relations = {
  'A': {
    'B': 'needed',
    'C': 'needed',
    'D': 'prohibited'
  },
  'B': {
    'E': 'prohibited'
  },
  'D': {
    'E': 'needed'
  },
  'E':{/* added for simplicity */},
  'C': {
    'F': 'needed'
  },
  'F': {
    'G': 'prohibited'
  }
};
var tmp = {};
function checkRelations(start) {
  for (var relation in relations[start]) {
    if (!tmp.hasOwnProperty(relation)) {
       tmp[relation] = {};
    }
    if (relations[start][relation] === 'needed') {
      tmp[relation][start] = 'needed';
    } else if (relations[start][relation] === 'prohibited') {
      tmp[relation][start] = 'prohibited';
    }
    checkRelations(relation);
  }
}
function run(obj) {
  for (var e in obj) {
    checkRelations(e);
  }
}

run(relations);
JSON.stringify(tmp);
```

will get you this result:

```
{
  'B': {
    'A': 'needed',
    'S': 'prohibited'
  },
  'E': {
    'B': 'prohibited',
    'D': 'needed'
  },
  'C': {
    'A': 'needed'
  },
  'F': {
    'C': 'needed'
  },
  'G': {
    'F': 'prohibited'
  },
  'D': {
    'A': 'prohibited',
    'T': 'prohibited'
  },
  'S': {
    'U': 'needed'
  }
}
```

As you can see from the very first entry `B`: your database is under-defined. What happens to every element that is not defined? What is the default if something is not defined, is it `prohibited` or 'needed'? If `'A'` needs `'B'` does that imply that `'B'` needs `'A'`?

Once you have defined that you can fill the first layer of the database (automatically) and build a tree (dito automatically) based on that if you want and safe a lot of processing (O(n^2)) by spending a lot of memory (O(n^2)).

All under the assumption that the whole thing is consistent and has no infinity loop anywhere!

With the default value set to `'meh'` the first round is

```
function checkRelations(start) {
  for (var relation in relations[start]) {
    if (!relations.hasOwnProperty(relation)) {
      relations[relation] = {
      };
    }
    if (relations[start][relation] === 'needed') {
      relations[relation][start] = 'meh';
    } else if (relations[start][relation] === 'prohibited') {
      relations[relation][start] = 'prohibited';
    }
    for (var r in relations) {
      if (!relations[relation].hasOwnProperty(r) && relation != r) {
        relations[relation][r] = 'meh';
      }
    }
  }
}
function run(obj) {
  for (var e in obj) {
    // fill database up
    checkRelations(e);
  }
}
run(relations);
JSON.stringify(relations)
{
  'A': {
    'B': 'needed',
    'C': 'needed',
    'D': 'prohibited',
    'E': 'meh',
    'F': 'meh',
    'S': 'meh',
    'T': 'meh',
    'U': 'meh',
    'G': 'meh'
  },
  'B': {
    'E': 'prohibited',
    'A': 'meh',
    'D': 'meh',
    'C': 'meh',
    'F': 'meh',
    'S': 'prohibited',
    'T': 'meh',
    'U': 'meh',
    'G': 'meh'
  },
  'E': {
    'B': 'prohibited',
    'A': 'meh',
    'D': 'meh',
    'C': 'meh',
    'F': 'meh',
    'S': 'meh',
    'T': 'meh',
    'U': 'meh',
    'G': 'meh'
  },
  'D': {
    'E': 'needed',
    'A': 'prohibited',
    'B': 'meh',
    'C': 'meh',
    'F': 'meh',
    'S': 'meh',
    'T': 'prohibited',
    'U': 'meh',
    'G': 'meh'
  },
  'C': {
    'F': 'needed',
    'A': 'meh',
    'B': 'meh',
    'E': 'meh',
    'D': 'meh',
    'S': 'meh',
    'T': 'meh',
    'U': 'meh',
    'G': 'meh'
  },
  'F': {
    'G': 'prohibited',
    'A': 'meh',
    'B': 'meh',
    'E': 'meh',
    'D': 'meh',
    'C': 'meh',
    'S': 'meh',
    'T': 'meh',
    'U': 'meh'
  },
  'S': {
    'B': 'prohibited',
    'A': 'meh',
    'E': 'meh',
    'D': 'meh',
    'C': 'meh',
    'F': 'meh',
    'T': 'meh',
    'U': 'meh',
    'G': 'meh'
  },
  'T': {
    'D': 'prohibited',
    'A': 'meh',
    'B': 'meh',
    'E': 'meh',
    'C': 'meh',
    'F': 'meh',
    'S': 'meh',
    'U': 'meh',
    'G': 'meh'
  },
  'U': {
    'S': 'needed',
    'A': 'meh',
    'B': 'meh',
    'E': 'meh',
    'D': 'meh',
    'C': 'meh',
    'F': 'meh',
    'T': 'meh',
    'G': 'meh'
  },
  'G': {
    'F': 'prohibited',
    'A': 'meh',
    'B': 'meh',
    'E': 'meh',
    'D': 'meh',
    'C': 'meh',
    'S': 'meh',
    'T': 'meh',
    'U': 'meh'
  }
}
```

That was already expensive. You can expand the tree but I would stop here and build the tree on-the-fly by following the path `'needed'`. You should be able to use the first recursive method to do it and recurse if you found a '`needed`' if the default is `'prohibited'`.

Example:

```
A - B(n) - C(n) - D(p)        
    |       |
    E(p)   F(n)
    ||      |
    S(p)   G(p)
```

(one bar is a branch, two bars are in a leaf)

Handle the `'meh'`parts depending on the defaults, of course. You can even skip the construction of the `'meh'` entries completely if the default is `'prohibited'` which leaves you with the `'needed'` entries only.

The rest would be

```
{
  'A': {
    'B': 'needed',
    'C': 'needed'
  },
  'B': {
    'nothing':0
  },
  'E': {
    'nothing':0
  },
  'D': {
    'E': 'needed'
  },
  'C': {
    'F': 'needed'
  },
  'F': {
    'nothing':0
  },
  'S': {
    'nothing':0
  },
  'T': {
    'nothing':0
  },
  'U': {
    'S': 'needed'
  },
  'G': {
    'nothing':0
  }
}
```

And reduced to the bare minimum:

```
{
  'A': {
    'B': 'needed',
    'C': 'needed'
  }
  'D': {
    'E': 'needed'
  },
  'C': {
    'F': 'needed'
  }
  'U': {
    'S': 'needed'
  }
}
```

The full algorithm: set all entries to `'prohibited'` if needed and travese the little DB listed above which has been made by the following little script

```
function checkRelations(start) {
  for (var relation in relations[start]) {
    if (relations[start][relation] === 'prohibited') {
      delete relations[start][relation];
    }
  }
}
function isEmpty(obj) {
  for(var p in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(p)){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
function run(obj) {
  for (var e in obj) {
    // fill database up
    checkRelations(e);
    // delete empty entries
    if(isEmpty(relations[e])){
      delete relations[e];
    }
  }
}
```

The function to traverse the last one:

```
function followPath(start){
  for (var relation in reduced[start]) {
    console.log(relation + " is needed")
    if (reduced.hasOwnProperty(relation)) {
      console.log( relation + " is needed, follow path")
      followPath(relation);
    }
  }
```

}

Ah, to late. Again ;-)

But at least it is a bit simpler (and faster, if I count the loops correctly) than I thought in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that simple. This solution doesn't take into account, that the relations affect each other reversely. I've edited the question to show the main problem more explicit. Checkboxes S, T and U added. If you click on A, B will be deactivated. So the function runs again for B, so E will be deactivated. But it doesn't take into account, that S needs to be deactivated, because S doesn't allow B. In this consequence, U needs to be deactivated as well, because it needs S.

Comment: Your description of the logic in code does not follow what you have written in  this comment. You have to rewrite the object, not the code. If you want to prohibit `S` then you have to do it explicitely ` 'A': {  'B': 'needed',  'C': 'needed',  'D': 'prohibited', 'S': 'prohibited', 'U': 'prohibited' }`

Comment: Ah, I think I see where my misunderstanding happened. You want it done automatically. OK, that's a hard one and may take some time.

Comment: Yes, since the underlying structure is very flexible. The relations can change anytime. It can happen, that B will be removed from the object because of an unspecified event. So actually maybe the simple recursive approach would do the trick. But then a function would need to enrich the object by all possible relations (converting all possible intermediate relations into direct relations).

Answer (score 1):

The kind of relations that you give as an example can be represented as a directed graph with labeled edges:

[image: Graph]

In the image above the color of an edge represent the label or the tag of an edge:
green: needs 
red: prohibits

The dot on the edge represents the direction of a relation.

Now that you know that you can make use of the graph theory algorithms to traverse/search the data. See: 
[Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)
[Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

In javascript I would store the data like this:

```
var graph = { v: [], e: [] } // v: vertices or nodes, e: edges
```

It's up to you how a vertex or node will look like. It could be a string or in your case it could be a html checkbox element or even an object containing both:

```
var vertex = { 
  name: "A",
  el : someElement
};
```

An edge in a directed graph will look like this:

```
var edge = {
  s: sourceVertex,
  d: destinationVertex,
  tag: "n"   // the tag will define the type of relation
  // again you can use strings: 'n' - `needs` and 'p' - `prohibits`
  // or whatever type you like       
};
```

JS Fiddle: [SO33673055](https://jsfiddle.net/19Ldvy05/1/)
I'm not yet sure this is what you need. Starting with the checkbox changed by the user all rules are checked only once.

Comment: This sounds interesting. I am not sure yet, if I understand it good enough to use it for a working solution. But I'll experiment with it.

Comment: OK. Later I will try to post a working example on jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you for your solution and the fiddle. It's pretty impressive yet hard to understand (for me). I'll try to implement this the next few days. So far it works good in a testing environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a rule based engine like nools

https://github.com/C2FO/nools

It can be overkill for this particular scenario but it can guarantee a solid solution to this problem if it gets more complicated